# Scale Bar in C# WPF with EMGU

Tags: c#, wpf, image, emgucv

Is it possible to overlay a scale bar into an image been displayed in WPF using EMGU like in the following picture?

[image]

Or like in Bing Maps.

I have images that are 1024x600 size, and I want to display on the image the scale of scale bar (I know the pixel size).

For example in the above image I would like to overlay to my image a green line and say that this line is 5cm.

I know how to do the calculations that relate the length of the line to the actual dimensions, however I don't know how to create that scale bar and overlay it on top of the image.

Any information about what approach I shall follow would be welcome!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF I have found the easiest way to do this is to use your image as the background of a Canvas control. Canvas controls allow the placement of any control anywhere on the canvas. I am using a similar technique in a product we are developing.

Doug

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this approach!